# Understanding theorem 7.1 in Wong, An introduction to pseudo differential operators.

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

[image]

Hello. I cannot verify some statements in this theorem.

**question 1**. $\text{supp}(\psi_k)\subset \left\{\xi:2^{k-2}\leq |\xi|\leq 2^{k+1}\right\}.$

My attempt: If $\xi\in \text{supp}(\psi_k)$ then $\psi_k(\xi)\neq 0,$ i.e $\psi(\frac{\xi}{2^{k-1}})\neq 0$. The latter occurs when $1\leq \frac{\xi}{2^{k-1}}\leq 2$ i.e when $2^{k-1}\leq |\xi|\leq 2^{k+1}$. But, in the sentence, appears $2^{k-2}\leq |\xi|.$

**question 2**. The series $\Psi(\xi)$ contains at most three nonzero consecutive terms.

My attemp: If $\Psi(\xi)$ contains more than three elements nonzero, without losing generality and to understand the problem, let $\psi_1(\xi),\psi_2(\xi),\psi_3(\xi),\psi_4(\xi)\neq 0$. Then (because this $\xi$ is in $\text{supp}(\psi_k)$, $k=1,2,3,4$.
\begin{eqnarray}
2^{-1}\leq |\xi|\leq 2^{2}\\
2^{0}\leq |\xi|\leq 2^3\\
2^1\leq |\xi|\leq 2^4\\
2^{2}\leq |\xi|\leq 2^5
\end{eqnarray}
therefore $2^2\leq |\xi|\leq 2^2$ i.e $|\xi|=4$ but I don't see how to get a contradiction with this.

**question 3**. This implies that for each $\xi_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $\xi_0$ and a positive integer $N$ such that $\psi_k(\xi)=0$ for all $\xi\in U$ and $k>N$. Hence $\Psi\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^n}).$

why?